# Cannot remove duplicate GitHub repo from Developer Story

Tags: support, bug, developer-story

I tried to add GitHub repo to a Developer Story but it did not appear in Story View. The start date and end date were both November 2016, and it should have appeared on top.

Screenshot:

[image]

Then I tried adding it again but that didn't change anything. So I thought maybe I accidentally clicked Cancel instead of Save and tried again. Nothing happened again. But after I switched to a "Traditional View" I found both duplicates repositories, and I can't find a way to remove them.

Screenshot:

[image]